# K-fold cross validation for hierarchical data sets in a mixed effects framework (glmer)

Tags: cross-validation, lme4-nlme

I would like to evaluate the predictive performance of my mixed effects logistic regression model using package lme4 (glmer). My model is as follows:

`glmer(R0A1~MP_Scaled+MPHW_Scaled+HW_Scaled+YP_Scaled+AG_Scaled+SS_Scaled+PR_Scaled+SR_Scaled+(1|Animal_ID)+(1|Year),data=males, family=binomial(link="logit"),nAGQ = 0)`

My data set is structured as follows: [image]

The only packages that I've found to be useful is DAAG or cv.glm; however, these packages are based on generalized linear models. Given the nested structure of my data (locations of animals nested within Animal ID), would these packages be appropriate to conduct a k-fold cross validation. In other words, I would have to remove the random effects and run the packages, which I wonder whether that influences the output, especially given the hierarchical structure of the data.

Answer (score 3):

I often work with hierarchical/nested data (e.g. many more or less repeated measurements of few patients) and find that I really need to split at the uppermost level of the data hierarchy. Not doing this and using the standard row-wise CV can in my experience lead to underestimating the error by an order of magnitude.

So if your locations are nested within animals, I'd recommend cross-validating animals. If you have (partially) crossed observations, e.g. animals x year you may need to make sure that test data is independent both wrt. animal and year.

AFAIK, the [github version of Andreas Alfons' `cvTools` package](https://github.com/aalfons/cvTools) supports giving groups to obey in splitting.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Is the coding you're referring to with cvtools as follows:   cvFolds(n, K = 5, R = 1,
    type = c("random", "consecutive", "interleaved"),
    grouping = NULL)

Comment: I'm not really familiar with cvtools. Does it work with glmer mixed models?

Comment: Well, instead of `grouping = NULL` you'd give your groups. `cvTools` works with all kinds of models, you hand over the function to do the training and also specify how to evaluate (i.e. what figure of merit you want).